# How to get URL for the first page of post archive

Tags: urls, paginate-links

I would like to get the first page of an archive. I have an archive with events. /events display events, which are not finished yet. /events?past display past events. I use `get/remove_query_arg` to generate an URL for a link, so that users can switch between past and future events. The problem is, if user is at page x in past events and try to switch to future events. Future events may not have the page x. This results in an error. URL is generated like this:

```
esc_url(remove_query_arg('past'))

esc_url(add_query_arg('past', ''))
```

This method preserves the page number within the URL:
at `/events/page/88?past` URL for future events becomes `/events/page/88`, which doesn't exist.

I was wondering if there is a "WordPress way" of doing this?

Comment: Is that a custom post type archive? What is the slug for that CPT?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż yes it is and the slug is "events".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get link to post type archive using... [‘get_post_type_archive_link’](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type_archive_link) function:

```
esc_url(add_query_arg('past', '', get_post_type_archive_link('events')));
```

Comment: Yes, this looks like a better solution than using regex replace.

Comment: @Genom also it’s safer - you shouldn’t use ‘add_query_arg’ without url param